# Using a progress bar in a functional expression

Tags: functions, dynamic

If we have a procedural construct like a `Do` loop or `Table`, it is straightforward to make a progress bar to indicate the percent completion of the task. For example:

```
f[k_] := RandomInteger[{-k, k}, 1000000];
ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[k/100]]
Do[f[k], {k, Range[100]}]
```

Replacing `Do` by `Table` works as well. But I have grown fond of the "functional style" using `Map`:

```
f[#]& /@ Range[100]
```

Is there a way to make a progress indicator that works with this style of iteration?

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78014/5478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include an iterator along with the function in the mapping:

```
k = 0; (++k; f[#]) & /@ Range[100];
```