# Finish(Asynchronous)Dynamic[]

Tags: front-end, kernel, system, scheduling

I have a question deriving from a recent topic [Synchronizing Dynamics with EventActions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120414/5478).

#### tl;dr;

How to authoritatively explain the influence of `SynchronousUpdating->False` on behaviour of `Dynamic[x, ...]` after clicking `Button["test", x = 1; FinishDynamic[]; Pause[1]; x = 2 ]`.

#### Background

> [...] There is no queue; instead, the *front end* sends one evaluation at a time and **waits for the result before continuing with its other work**, [...] the front end is completely locked up, [...]
>
> -- [Synchronous versus Asynchronous Dynamic Evaluations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#681967067) about the *PreemptiveLink*

That is why, `x` here, won't be updated till the whole expression is evaluated (`x=2`).

```
Dynamic[x]

   (*We are deliberately ignoring Method->"Queued" to show the point*)
Button["test", x = 1; Pause[1]; x = 2 ]
```

We can use `FinishDynamic[]` (more in link at the top) to ask the *FrontEnd* to update all Dynamics. When `FinishDynamic[]` returns the *Kernel* can proceed with `Pause` and the rest.

```
 Button["test", x = 1; FinishDynamic[]; Pause[1]; x = 2 ]
```

It will only affect synchronous (default) `Dynamics` though. e.g. `Dynamic[x, SynchronousUpdating -> False]` won't be triggered.

#### The question

This brought me to the conclusion that the *MainLink* (asynchronous `Dynamics`) can't be used by a *FrontEnd* when a preemptive evaluation is going on (even if it is waiting for `FinishDynamic[]` to return).

Is that correct? Are there any official sources confirming that? Maybe it can be deduced from Dynamic related tutorials?

#### Loose thoughts

From what I understand, *MainLink* evaluations are only sent (by *FE* to *K*) when the *Kernel* is "free", till then they are queued by a *FrontEnd*.

Mathematica knows that in this case waiting has no sense since the *Kernel* is waiting for the `FinishDynamic[]` and the *FrontEnd* would wait for `Dynamic` content evaluation.

That is why there isn't even such thing like `UpdateDynamicObjectsAsynchronous`, it would always end up in an infinite waiting from both sides.

Does it make sense?