# Performance issue of Manipulate with NSolve and Locator

Tags: performance-tuning, manipulate, front-end, dynamic, locator

I want to solve a nonlinear equation `eq` in a `Manipulate` environment as the following one using a `Locator`

```
Manipulate[
 eq = {u1*Cos[u2], u1*Sin[u2]};
 cond = 0 <= u1 <= 10 && 0 <= u2 < 2 Pi;
 nsol = NSolve[{p == eq, cond}, {u1, u2}, Reals] // Quiet;
 Grid[{
   {Graphics[{Point[p]}, PlotRange -> 5, Axes -> True]}
   , {nsol}
   }]
 , {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}
 ]
```

[image]

I am aware that the nonlinear equation is the transformation into cylindrical coordinates, and I know how to get these analytically. But this is just a simple example, later I want to solve other more complex equations with other conditions. I am interested in computing the solution smoothly while dragging the locator across the plot.

My problems are

1. the performance is poor (I suppose I have to use `Dynamic` sowhere but I dont know where and more importantly **why**). How do I have to program this correctly in order to have a smooth computation while dragging the locator in the graphic?
2. I have to tell `NSolve` to be `Quiet`, otherwise I get the warning, that the system can not be solved but with inexact coefficients (which is fine for me). Is there any other way to do this already in `NSolve`?

---

**EDIT: computation and usage of results of `NSolve`**

@Kuba: thank you for the information, I will read through everything you posted. I have a further question (which I was not able to solve with the first version of your answer), but if this is answered in the references you gave, then just say it and I will find my way there.

Sorry for expanding the question, but my first formulation was not precise. I would also want to use the results of `NSolve` for other purposes within `Manipulate`, e.g., computing a field with the results and drawing an arrow as follows

```
Manipulate[
 eq = {u1*Cos[u2], u1*Sin[u2]};
 cond = 0 <= u1 <= 10 && 0 <= u2 < 2 Pi;
 nsol = NSolve[{p == eq, cond}, {u1, u2}, Reals] // Quiet;
 field = {u1 + Cos[u2^2], -Sin[u2]};
 Grid[{
   {Graphics[{Point[p], Arrow[{p, p + field /. nsol[[1]]}]}, 
     PlotRange -> 5, Axes -> True]}
   , {nsol}
   , {field /. nsol[[1]]}
   }
  , Alignment -> Left
  ]
 , {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a must read before we proceed:

- [AdvancedDynamicFunctionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html)

especially `Nesting Dynamic` and `Synchronous versus Asynchronous Dynamic Evaluations` chapters.

---

Preemptive link calculations are blocking front end till they return the result. That is why locator feels heavy, you won't see next position update till `NSolve` is finished.

So we need to run it through the main link (`SynchornousUpdating->False`) while the rest is separated (by additional `Dynamic` in `Point`) to not create repeatedly this part.

```
Manipulate[

 Grid[{{
    Graphics[{Point[Dynamic@p]}, PlotRange -> 5, Axes -> True]
    }, {
    Dynamic[
     eq = {u1*Cos[u2], u1*Sin[u2]};
     cond = 0 <= u1 <= 10 && 0 <= u2 < 2 Pi;
     nsol = NSolve[{p == eq, cond}, {u1, u2}, Reals] // Quiet;
     nsol
     ,
     TrackedSymbols :> {p},
     SynchronousUpdating -> False
     ]
    }}
  ],
 {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Related topics:

- [Synchronizing code in Dynamics with other procedures](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120818/5478)

Comment: Thank you veeeery much for the references! One question (see may be new edit of question): is it also possible to use the results of `NSolve` also for further computations and objects (for example an arrow in the graphics)?

Comment: @MauricioLobos With `field = {u1 + Cos[u2^2], -Sin[u2]}` added to Dynamic and `Dynamic@Arrow[{p, p + field /. nsol[[1]]}]` added to graphics it seems to work.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, got it!