# Initializing Manipulate without grey bar

Tags: front-end, manipulate, gui-construction, scheduling

I have a relatively long code inside [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) that computes an output depending on controls. Computation takes about a second, so I am using `SynchronousUpdating->False`. However, when I do it, initialization of the object is not nice when the content is displayed for the first time. Not only is it a plain bar, but also it shows a misleading tooltip if the mouse is over it (the dynamic is not disabled, and after a second you get a normal object):

```
Manipulate[Pause[1]; x, {x, 0, 1}, SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

> [image]

I tried to use `SynchronousInitialization -> False`, which does what I want:

> [image: Blockquote]

But it only works when `SynchronousUpdating -> True`. If it is `False`, as I need, it doesn't work.

Any ideas how to make the initialization prettier and keep the [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)responsive?

Comment: Can you push some computation time to the ``Initialization`` option of the `Manipulate`? Worst case, a quick `DynamicModule` with some `Control` specs isn't too bad here. There you can use three-function `Dynamic` to get a nicer display.

Comment: What version are you using? I don't see "Evaluating Initialization..." which is expected, since there isn't any Initialization.

Comment: An example where it appears and is expected is: `Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 1}, SynchronousInitialization -> False,  Initialization :> (Pause[1])]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

The original Kuba's code is slightly modified to 
1) ensure `finished` is initialized (added `Initialization` line); and 2) avoid slider handle being stuck sometimes and jump back (replaced built-in `Manipulate` control with an explicit `Slider`)

Here's what you can do:

```
DynamicModule[{finished, display}
  , Manipulate[
        DynamicWrapper[
            Dynamic[
                If[finished
                  , display
                  , ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Indeterminate"]
                ]
              , TrackedSymbols :> {finished}
            ]
          , finished = False
          ; Pause @ 1
          ; display = {x, x}
          ; finished = True
          , SynchronousUpdating -> False
        ]
      , Row[{Slider[Dynamic@x, {0, 1}]}]
      , Initialization :> (finished = False)

    ]
]
```

similar ideas are used in:

[Performance issue of Manipulate with NSolve and Locator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134785/5478)

[Button action monitored with progress bar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78014/5478)

[How to Initiate a queued evaluation from a Dynamic GUI without using a Button](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19174/5478)

[Working with DynamicModule: Tracking the progress of Initialization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59949/5478)

Comment: Perfect! You are GUI wizard :). Slight modifications added to your code!