# CreateDocument fails to open when ExpressionCell has RegionMember function

Tags: functions, function-construction, notebooks, gui-construction

I am working on a code for a colleague where I am trying to compute the Bond Orientational Order for a cluster of particles. To make life easier for processing a large number of images I wish to implement a GUI (although it is not easy in Mathematica).

I have failed to understand why for the code below, `CreateDocument` fails to create a new notebook if the `ExpressionCell` has `RegionMember/@poly` as  argument. I can create the document when the expression is `ExpressionCell[poly]`and the cell displays the list of polygons. It seems like `RegionMember/@poly` does not evaluate whereas `poly` does.

Note:
There is no minimal example that I can post here for the purpose of the code I am dealing with. My actual code  for `packagedFunction` goes a bit beyond to generate the final results but I am posting it till the point where the problem originates.

for `imgs` kindly use the image:

[image]

**Code**

```
CreatePalette[
DynamicModule[{segmentImage, showFunc, deleteFalsePts, addPts, 
packagedFunction, img = imgs[[1]], ovimg, data},
Grid[{
{Button["create Voronoi", packagedFunction[data]]} ,
{Button["particle centroids", CreateDocument[{
    TextCell["Coordinate List", "Title"],
    TextCell[
     Row[{"Report generated @ ", DateString[], "\n", 
       "Particles #: ", Length@data}], "Text"],
    ExpressionCell[data, "Output"]
    }]
  ]} ,
{Pane[
  Dynamic@If[Head[img] === Image,
    LocatorPane[
     Dynamic@data, ovimg, LocatorAutoCreate -> All,
     Appearance -> Style["*", 20, Red]]
    ]
  ]
 }
}],
Initialization :> (
segmentImage[img_, circ_: 0.95, thresh_: {10, 50}] := 
 SelectComponents[
     ColorNegate@
      DeleteSmallComponents@
       MorphologicalBinarize@
        img, (First[thresh] <= #Count < 
         Last[thresh] && #Circularity > circ) &] // 
    MorphologicalComponents // 
   ComponentMeasurements[#, "Centroid"] & // Values;

data = segmentImage@img;

showFunc[img_, pts_] := 
 Show[img, 
  Graphics[{XYZColor[0, 0, 1, 0.4], Thickness[0.005], 
    Circle[#, 8] & /@ pts}]];

ovimg = showFunc[img, data];

packagedFunction[pts_?(Length@# > 1 &)] := 
 Block[{delMesh, vertexcoords, vertexconn, cellNeighCoords, angles,
   anglesC, poly, pos, polyOrdered, colourVM},
  delMesh = DelaunayMesh@pts;
  vertexcoords = <|delMesh["VertexCoordinateRules"]|>;
  vertexconn = delMesh["VertexVertexConnectivityRules"];
  cellNeighCoords = With[{vertexpts = vertexcoords},
    FlattenAt[{Lookup[vertexpts, Keys@#], 
        Lookup[vertexpts, Values@#]}, {2}] & /@ vertexconn
    ];
  angles = (Abs[(Plus @@ Exp[6.0 I #])/Length@#]) & /@ 
    Map[Map[x \[Function] VectorAngle[{1, 0}, First[#] - x ], 
       Rest@#] &, cellNeighCoords];
  anglesC = ColorData["TemperatureMap", #] & /@ angles;
  poly = MeshPrimitives[VoronoiMesh[pts, None], 2];
  CreateDocument[{ExpressionCell[RegionMember /@ poly, Automatic]}] (* PROBLEM HERE? *)
  ];
)
], WindowTitle -> "BondOrientationalOrder"]
```

Comment: Is gui context related, have you tried to reproduce the problem just by running your procedure? And have you tried stripping all those image related procedures? The more you narrow it down the more likely you will focus attention?

Comment: @Kuba thanks. this does not happen with the non-GUI based version. It is in the context of GUI that RegionMember does not evaluate

Comment: @Kuba does not `ExpressionCell` handle any type of data `Graphics`, `Text` or even `RegionMemberFunction`?

Comment: As linked topic states, `Method -> "Queued"` will fix your problem. Since the calculation is long, please take a look at [Button action monitored with progress bar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78014/5478) to learn how to show to users that something is going on.

Comment: @Kuba thanks looking at it after a long time. i think it did the job !